# coffeescript vs. pure javascript for educational usage

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am working on an update of a curriculum for teaching non technical students the basics of programming, esp. programming for the web.

I prefer coffeescript over javascript for the (most times) much shorter and - as I think - better readable code.

On the other hand there are thousands of examples written in Javascript which are harder to understand if you know only about Coffeescript.

For the last years I just told my students to use a split screen in the editor, code CS in one frame and see JS in the other to see what is the translation of the CS statements in JS. And I showed the how to use CS2JS and JS2CS converter. The idea behind this is to make things visible like what "for-each" or "for-in" statements of CS do, as they are shown in JS in an unfolded way.

(I know this example leaks a little bit as ECMA 5 is rolled out now for a little time, but I am doing this for didactic reasons for a little while now)

Another problem is that there a not so much code hinter etc. for CS then for JS available.

**EDIT**

As the community seams to see this question to be opinion based, I precise it:

- What toolchain do you use to make an easy entrypoint available for newbees to learn CS?

---

My pipeline builds on brackets.io as a webservice, node, gerrit, gitlab, ungit, jenkins, jade, less, coffeescript, ...

I have the need to make everything available totally offline so I wrap the tools in docker containers and VMs.

Comment: Given that coffescript compiles to JavaScript I would teach/like to learn pure JavaScript first. Javascript is more explicit and so for those learning its easier to see whats happening. 
Once you have a solid base in that then introduce coffescript.

Comment: Or never introduce coffeescript.

Answer (score 1):

Before this question is closed as opinion-based, which indeed it is, let me comment that I cannot imagine the value in teaching non-technical students about CS vs. JS transpilation issues. They must have MUCH better things to spend their time on. As lovely as CS is, it is a dialect. Teaching it is like teaching Cockney slang in an English class. Furthermore, notwithstanding all the great code written in CS and the great benefits in efficiency it brought to those who used it, for better or for worse it is now on its way out, superseded by ES6 and TypeScript and eventually ES7.

Comment: I think I am missunderstood in the point of teaching transpilation issues.
That's not my point. I am using CS to teach basic programming skills and recognize that the students have the problem to use JS examples - that are available in a wide field of themes - even if they just have to let them automaticaly be translated to CS.
In other courses I teach JS where the students have problems with all the parenthesis and semicolons.

Comment: I know that ES6 and ES7 will have more prospects. But that seems not to be needed for the start, contrariwise it would be better to use a subset and don't start with promises or other nice concepts.

So the question is how to make things easier for the beginners, which tools to choose for illustrate concepts etc.

Thank you for your answer nevertheless.

Comment: If the community thinks that this kind of question is to far away from the topics of this forum, I'd like to ask any moderator to delete this question as I am not able to do it by myself after it is answered.